# SQL Server : remove duplicates and add columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has duplicate record this is how the table looks like.

```
ID Date             Status      ModifiedBy
------------------------------------------
1  1/2/2019 10:29   Assigned(0) xyz
1  1/2/2019 12:21   Pending(1)  abc
1  1/4/2019 11:42   Completed(5)abc
1  1/20/2019 2:45   Closed(8)   pqr
2  9/18/2018 10:05  Assigned(0) xyz
2  9/18/2018 11:15  Pending(1)  abc
2  9/21/2018 11:15  Completed(5)abc
2  10/7/2018 2:46   Closed(8)   pqr
```

What I want to do is take the minimum date value but also I want to add additional column which is `PendingStartDate` and `PendingEndDate`.

- `PendingStartDate`: date when ID went into pending status
- `PendingEndDate`: date when ID went from pending status to any other status

So my final output should look like this

```
ID AuditDate        Status      ModifiedBy PendingStartDate PendingEndDate
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  1/2/2019 10:29   Assigned(0) xyz        1/2/2019 12:21   1/4/2019 11:42
2  9/18/2018 10:05  Assigned(0) abc        9/18/2018 11:15  9/21/2018 11:15
```

Any help as to how to do this is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome Abdul. What have you tried so far? Can you share with us your current attempts and we can help you correct where you may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select id, min(date) as auditdate,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then status end) as status,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then modifiedBy end) as modifiedBy,
       min(case when status like 'Pending%' then date end) as pendingStartDate,
       max(case when status like 'Pending%' then next_date end) as pendingEndDate
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum,
             lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: The status after pending state can be any. It not necessarily be Completed.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
    Declare @Tab Table(Id int, [Date] DATETIME,[Status] Varchar(25),ModifiedBy varchar(10))

    Insert into @Tab
    SELECT 1,'1/2/2019 10:29','Assigned(0)','xyz' Union All
    SELECT 1,'1/2/2019 11:29','Started(0)','xyz' Union All
    SELECT 1,'1/2/2019 12:21','Pending(1)','abc'  Union All
    SELECT 1,'1/2/2019 12:21','In-Progress(1)','abc'  Union All
    SELECT 1,'1/4/2019 11:42','Completed(5)','abc'Union All
    SELECT 1,'1/20/2019 2:45','Closed(8)','pqr'   Union All
    SELECT 2,'9/18/2018 10:05','Assigned(0)','xyz'Union All
    SELECT 2,'9/18/2018 11:15','Pending(1)','abc' Union All
    SELECT 2,'9/21/2018 11:15','Completed(5)','abc' Union All
    SELECT 2,'10/7/2018 2:46','Closed(8)','pqr'


    ;with cte As
    (
     Select * ,lead(date) over (partition by id order by date) as pendingStartDate
     from @Tab
     Where Status in ('Assigned(0)','Pending(1)','Completed(5)')
    )

    ,cte2 As
    (
        Select * , lead(pendingStartDate) over (partition by id order by date) As pendingEndDate
        from cte
    )

    Select * from cte2 where Status ='Assigned(0)'
```

As you mentioned in comment, i have included few states between Assigned,pending and completed.